# pull text from .txt file Batch

Tags: batch-file

I need help with a batch file.

I have a .log file in which i search for a specific string but now i have trouble in my next step, i need search other string and then get a string between "" to use it in batch I'm not sure if this is posible.

Example:

```
set findtext="text2find"
set findfile="text.log"

findstr %findtext% %findfile%

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
findstr "Creating Environment " %findfile%
 if %errorlevel% == 0 (
 set Environment=[Text from log file]
 )
)
```

The log file contains a line:
Creating Environment "EnvironmentName"

EnvironmentName is the string that I need to use in batch file.

This is possible?

In advance thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes. You can use a `FOR /F` command to parse the output of the `FIND` or `FINDSTR` command.

Comment: Within a block (parenthesised sequence of lines), `%anyvariable%` is evaluated as the initial value of the variable, hence `%errorlevel%` will be replaced by `0` after the second `findstr`. The normal solution here is to use `if not errorlevel 1 ` which means `if the current errorlevel is neither 1 nor greater than 1` hence, is under normal circumstances, `0`. Note: no `%` involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
set "environmentname="
for /f "tokens=1,2*delims= " %%a in (%findfile%) do (
 if /i "%%~a%%~b"=="creatingenvironment" set "environmentname=%%~c"
)
if defined environmentname (
 echo environment name=%environmentname%
) else (
 echo environment name was not found
)
```

This should get your data. I've assumed you have already set `findfile` appropriately.

The `for /f` "tokenises" each line that it reads from the file. The line is interpreted as

*delimiters* token1 *delimiters* token2 *delimiters* token3...

where the set of characters following the `=` in the `delims` option (in this case, space) are defined as the delimiters.

The `tokens=...` defines which tokens will be selected. In this case token1 and token2 will be selected, as well as `*` which means "everything after the highest token number specified" so token3 *and the rest of the line* will be the third selection.

The first selection will be assigned to the defined `metavariable`, which is `%%a` in this case. The next will be assigned to `%%b` and so on. These `metavariables` are case-sensitive.

So, for the line in question, `%%a` gets `creating`, `%%b` gets `environment` and `%%c` gets `"EnvironmentName"`

The `if /i` compares case-insensitively (which is why I paid no heed to the case you have used). The `~` removes any quotes surrounding the contents of the metavariable, so `%%~a%%~b` will be `creatingenvironment` for the target line. When that line is detected, assign the remainder of the line - enclosing quotes (`%%~c`) to the variable.

When the file has been processed, see whether the variable was set and report either its contents or that it hasn't been set (which is why it was explicitly set to *nothing* before the file was processed.

Note that I've just typed this on-the-fly, I haven't tested it. There may be errors - which is why war-and-peace for variablenames is a drawback. Variablenames are case-insensitive.

If your filename contains spaces, then you'd need

```
for /f "usebackqtokens=1,2*delims= " %%a in ("%findfile%") do (
```

(that will also work for filenames without spaces, of course - but introduces an extra element that doesn't need to be explained immediately in the context of the detection of the required data)